Scanner doesnt work on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I recently upgraded my desktop to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
My printer didn't work had to install driver from database 'HPEnvy 4520'. Printer OK
However Document Scanner doesn't work:
can see the scanner HP ENVY4524 but
FAIL TO SCAN
FEEDER EMPTY.
There is no feeder on this printer

which scan program are you using? If its Document Scanner try setting the esc option in the device drop down (if offered)

Thanks Graham.  Brilliant

I'll post that as an answer if you'd care to accept it then others with the same issue can find a solutions too. Thanks.

Hi Graham, I'd like to accept but dont know how to.

this help page explains. Simply click on the grey tick mark under the vote section alongside the answer. You can upvote too. Thanks

In Document Scanner (the default scan application) select the eSCL option from the drop down menu.

What is eSCL
Mopria eSCL Specification

The eSCL specification defines the interfaces, data types and overall behavioral model for driving a scanner engine from various classes of clients: Software, Cloud Services, Mobile Device, Embedded Web Server (EWS).
Compliance with the Mopria eSCL specification allows millions of Mopria certified multi-function printers and scanners to work with personal computing and mobile platforms. The specification is publicly available to enable companies to implement and support eSCL.

Reference and acknowledgements

Why does ecs refer to this particular scanner?

@ArchismanPanigrahi explanation and spec for eSCL if that helps. I just know it works on my device

@graham It works! What a simple solution!! Thanks. I would like to know though why it stopped to work in normal mode without any upgrade or install (except updates), if you know.

No idea why it stopped with the normal mode but I find now having selected it that eSCL is automatically selected on future scans and normal on normal scans.
